# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token on jquery bootgrid

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to make an ajax call to c# method via jquery bootgrid, but when I do it I got this error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2"

This is the JS Code:

```
$("#grid-data").bootgrid({
    ajax: true,
    url: "SomeUrl.aspx/MethodName",
    formatters: {
        "commands": function (column, row) {
            return "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-default command-edit\" data-row-id=\"" + row.school_id + "\">edit</span></button> " + "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-default command-delete\" data-row-id=\"" + row.school_id + "\">delete</span></button>";
        }
    },
});
```

and this is the c# code:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = false, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static DTOGridResult MethodName(int? current, int? rowCount, string sort, string searchPhrase)
    {
        ..some code...
    }
```

what am i doing wrong?

This is the home page of jquery bootgrid
http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/

Comment: you got the error from the browser, or from the server? but pretty much ANYTIME you get "unexpected token < in json", it means you don't have json. you have html+json.

Comment: Try to validate your json as well using tools like [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: it from the browser. i dont understand what i can do to fix it. i have tried to make the same as the example on the official site and got the same error:http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Examples#data-api

Comment: Did you try adding `dataType: 'json'` to your ajax request? I believe you're supposed to tell the web service what type of data format you want returned; otherwise it defaults to XML.

Comment: I have added dataType: 'json'. It still have the same problem.